# How to have a nested foreach loop without having duplicate child records

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm a beginner and new to Codeigniter3. I've made a checklist system which has two radio buttons, Fine and Not fine. A person will check if all the options are fine or not. If there is an issue in any option he will select not fine. Then on the "Issues" page I'm only showing the options he selected "Not fine". He will be able to add multiple comments on each Issue. I've done all this part. The only problem I'm facing is how to show the comments under every option? What's happing now is for eg. I have 3 issues and each issue has 1 comment but will still show all the comments under each and every option. I know this is the normal behavior of nested loop but I don't know how to show the comments under their own respective issues.

```
<?php foreach($issues as $i=>$issue) : ?>

   <div class="form-row col-md-5">
        <!-- Radio Group -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">     
             <h6><?php echo $issue['checks']; ?></h6>
        </div>
                                            
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <?php foreach($comments as $comment) : ?>
                 <label class="input-group input-group-sm mb-4">
                   <input type="hidden" name="chk_value[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $issue['checks']; ?>">
                   <input type="text" name="comment[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $comment['comment']; ?>" class="form-control">
                 </label>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
       </div>
                                            
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-1"></div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Check if the current issue in your loop is the same as in a comment. Not sure how you related them

Comment: Thanks for your reply @brombeer. Both foreach loops are looping different tables, the "issues" foreach is getting record from checklist table and the comments foreach loop is getting record from comment table

Comment: How are your comments related to an issue? How do you know f.e. comment #3 "belongs to" issue #12? There has to be a relation between those two

Comment: You are right. I'll add now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be a lack of relation between issues and comments. I'm not sure what your data structure is, but you should either make it nested, and then use it like this

```
foreach($issues as $issue){
  foreach($issue['comments'] as $comment){
    //show comment
  }
}
```

or have some kind of 'id' that could link them

```
foreach($issues as $issue){
  foreach($comments as $comment){
    if($comment['issue_id'] == $issue['id']){
      //show comment
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually both foreach are getting records from different tables